# Limit, x approaching infinity, don't understand simplification step

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

Can someone please explain how the simplification from the fraction with the 7n's to the $1/(49x^2+7x)$ fraction was done? I have no clue how they got fro one to the other.

Comment: $(7x + 1)! = (7x + 1)*(7x)*(7x - 1)!$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the definition of factorial:

$$(7x + 1)! = (7x+1)\cdot(7x)\cdot (7x-1)!$$

Thence

$$\frac{(7x-1)!}{(7x+1)!} = \frac{(7x-1)!}{(7x+1)\cdot(7x)\cdot (7x-1)!} = \frac{1}{7x(7x+1)} = \frac{1}{49x^2 + 7x}$$